# Django rest framework Field name `ia_superuser` is not valid for model `CustomUser`

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I got stock with writing custom user in Django an rest framework.I've written custom user and custom serializer, I've added every necessaries in settings.py.
When I try to go to user app I get this error:

ImproperlyConfigured at /api/user/

Field name `ia_superuser` is not valid for model `CustomUser`.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/
Django Version:     3.0.8
Exception Type:     ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value:

Field name `ia_superuser` is not valid for model `CustomUser`.

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Aireza.virtualenvs\lcodev-lF6rFvWb\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py in build_unknown_field, line 1340
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Aireza.virtualenvs\lcodev-lF6rFvWb\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.10.2
Python Path:

['F:\Python\lcodev\ecom',
'C:\Users\Aireza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python310.zip',
'C:\Users\Aireza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\DLLs',
'C:\Users\Aireza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib',
'C:\Users\Aireza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310',
'C:\Users\Aireza\.virtualenvs\lcodev-lF6rFvWb',
'C:\Users\Aireza\.virtualenvs\lcodev-lF6rFvWb\lib\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 22 Mar 2022 11:34:45 +0000

I have an api app in the project and the user app is in the api app.

anyone can help?
thanks

**here's everything:**

**user serializer.py:**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes,permission_classes


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def create(self,validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password',None) # pop method removes the given index from the list and returns it
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)

        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self,instance , validated_data):
        for attr,value in validated_data.item():
            if attr == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)
            else:
                setattr(instance,attr,value)

        instance.save()
        return instance


    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only':True}}
        fields = ('name' , 'email' , 'phone' ,'password','is_active' , 'is_staff', 'ia_superuser',)
        read_only_fields = ('email',)
```

**user model.py:**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
# Create your models here.


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default='user')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=200 , unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    username = None                # we dont want the user to be logged in by username
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    session_token = models.CharField(max_length=10,default=0)
```

**user views.py:**

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from .models import CustomUser
from .serializers import UserSerializer
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model,login,logout
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
import random , re
# Create your views here.


def generate_session_token(length = 10):
    return ''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(
        [chr(i) for i in range(97,123)] + [str(j) for j in range(10)]
    ) for k in range(length))



@csrf_exempt
def signin(request):
    if not request.method == 'POST':
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Send a post request with valid paramenter only'})

    # print(request.POST.get('email', None))  - if you will not get email, None will be printed
    username = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']

    print(username)
    print(password)

# validation part
    if not re.match("^[\w\.\+\-]+\@[\w]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$", username):
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Enter a valid email'})

    if len(password) < 3:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Password needs to be at least of 3 char'})

    UserModel = get_user_model()

    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)

        if user.check_password(password):
            usr_dict = UserModel.objects.filter(
                email=username).values().first()
            usr_dict.pop('password')

            if user.session_token != "0":
                user.session_token = "0"
                user.save()
                return JsonResponse({'error': "Previous session exists!"})

            token = generate_session_token()
            user.session_token = token
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return JsonResponse({'token': token, 'user': usr_dict})
        else:
            return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid password'})

    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid Email'})


def signout(request, id):
    logout(request)

    UserModel = get_user_model()

    try:
        user = UserModel.objects.get(pk=id)
        user.session_token = "0"
        user.save()

    except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid user ID'})

    return JsonResponse({'success': 'Logout success'})


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes_by_action = {'create' : [AllowAny]}
    queryset = CustomUser.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        try:
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes_by_action[self.action]]
        except KeyError:
            return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

**api migrations 0001_initial.py:**

```py
from django.db import migrations
from api.user.models import CustomUser


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    def seed_data(apps, schema_editor):
        user = CustomUser(name="hitesh",
                          email="hitesh@lco.dev",
                          is_staff=True,
                          is_superuser=True,
                          phone="987654321",

                          )
        user.set_password("12345")
        user.save()

    dependencies = [

    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(seed_data),
    ]
```

**user urls.py:**

```py
from django.urls import path,include
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register('',views.UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
path('login/',views.signin, name = 'signin'),
    path('logout/<int:id>/',views.signout, name = 'signout'),
    path('user/',views.UserViewSet),
    path('',include(router.urls)),
]
```

**settings.py:**

```py
"""
Django settings for ecom project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'iqlfys_luymme_hqvp-+!iy@xnk2)(m(k=4!_tl4xpr9gqmofs'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'api',
    'api.category',
    'api.product',
    'api.user',
    'api.order',
    'api.payment'




]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'ecom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'ecom.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.CustomUser"

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ]
}
```

Comment: It is `is_superuser`, not `ia_superuser`.

Comment: It makes more sense to be is_superuser but I’ve copied the exact error!

Comment: I'm not talking about the error message, I'm talking about the fact that you used `ia_superuser` in your code, so a typo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

perhaps you are looking for `is_superuser`?

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_superuser

Edited:
I think you'll just need to update the `UserSerializer` class as such:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    def create(self,validated_data):
        ...
        return instance

    def update(self,instance , validated_data):
        ...
        return instance


    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        extra_kwargs = {'password':{'write_only':True}}
        fields = (
            'name' ,
            'email',
            'phone',
            'password',
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',)
        # note: it's changed from "ia_superuser" to "issuperuser"
        read_only_fields = ('email',)
```

Comment: It makes more sense to be is_superuser but I’ve copied the exact error!

Comment: @alirezamoosavian I've edited my answer, I think you'll just need to change `ia_superuser` to `is_superuser` in your `UserSerializer` class

Comment: yeees that was the problem, thank so much for your answer.